# Which object in JavaScript holds "<head>..</head>"?

Tags: javascript, firefox

On `firefox` browser console, I could access `<body></body>` container as shown below.

```
> window
        [object Window]
> documentObject = window["document"];
        [object HTMLDocument]
> documentObject["body"]
        [object HTMLBodyElement]
```

Please let me know, How do I access `<head></head>` container?

*Note: Please do not recommend `getElementByTagName` kind of methods. I am trying to access the way I did above using dictionary syntax.*

Comment: What are you going to do next with `head`?

Comment: @АнатолийИвашов It has been 2 days, I started working with JS. I realised that any object in JS is dictionary(String:value). So, I just wondered, why can't I found "head"(key) property in console under `window->document` object, unlike "body"(key) property.

Comment: @overexchange I use Chrome. In Chrome's console, as you write **object's name**, the available properties and methods of that object show up right in a dropdown. If that feature isn't available in Firefox then I would recommend you to download Chrome too. It helps alot in debugging and learning. The console not only show props and meths of built-in objects but if you had created an object, it will also help you with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `document.head`? You can access body like: `document.body`. You can also do it like this: `window.document.head` and `window.document.body` but adding `window` won't change anything. Former and latter are the same.

You can also use `computed member access` operator:

```
var head = document['head']; // Same as: window['document']['head']
var body = document['body']; // Same as: window['document']['body']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access a head element by using getElementsByTagName():

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("HEAD")[0].innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at jQuery source code, you'll find this:

```
var head = document.head ||
           document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] ||
           document.documentElement;
```